# Sequence space norms

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

My tutorial instructor told me today that the sequence space norms $l^2$ and $l^3$ are equivalent but the norms $l^1$ and $l^2$ are not equivalent norms ?

However I could prove that $\|x\|_2 \le \|x\|_1 \le \sqrt{n} \|x\|_2$.  So the sequence space norms $l_1$ and $l_2$ are equivalent.  Am I right ?

Moreover can somebody give me an example of two norms which are not equivalent ?

Edit 1:- $n$ is the dimension of the space.  The space under consideration is $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: In finite dimensions (where stating $n$ makes sense) all norms are equivalent.

Comment: So in an infinite dimensional vector space $l^2$ and $l^3$ norms are not equivalent. Am I right ?

Comment: What does "equivalent" mean when the spaces are different? Say, $(1,1/\sqrt2,\ldots,1/\sqrt n,\ldots )$ is in $\ell^3$ but not in $\ell^2$.

Comment: Maybe take $\ell^2$ as subspace of $\ell^3$.

Comment: You already have an answer to the question as stated now (all norms in $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent). So change the question if you are asking for something else.